# How to filters the record using xslt parameters

Tags: xslt

I am using xml and xslt to generate desired html. In my previous post, I was able to generate the all the records, however I am little confuse how to get filter data according xslt parameter values.

I have two controls in my page first is for selection and second is for displaying the records as per the values passed from the selection control.

Below are the xmls and xslt which is used to generate the second usercontrol (displaying all the records).

1) Destinations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list type="Destinations">
<resources location="include/xml/locations.xml">
<publication>481</publication>
</resources>
<destination id="594051" title="Sydney" url="/asiapacific/australia/sydney.aspx" >
<city id="192409" />
</destination>
<destination id="594088" title="Brisbane" url="/asiapacific/australia/brisbane.aspx" >
<city id="192397" />
</destination>
<destination id="594579" title="Dubai" url="/middleeast/uae/dubai.aspx" >
<city id="192855" />
</destination>
<destination id="594580" title="Abu Dhabi" url="/middleeast/uae/abudhabi.aspx" >
<city id="192851" />
</destination>
</list>
```

2) Locations.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list type="Locations">
<region id="192393" code="ASIA" name="Asia &amp; the Pacific" shortname="Asia &amp; the Pacific">
<country id="192395" code="AU" name="Australia" shortname="Australia">
<city id="192397" code="BNE" name="Brisbane" shortname="Brisbane">
<airport id="192399" code="BNE" name="Brisbane International Airport" shortname="Brisbane"></airport>
</city>
<city id="192409" code="SYD" name="Sydney" shortname="Sydney">
<airport id="192411" code="SYD" name="Kingsford Smith Airport" shortname="Sydney"></airport>
</city>
</country>
</region>
<region id="192847" code="MEAF" name="The Middle East &amp; Africa" shortname="The Middle East &amp; Africa">
<country id="192849" code="AE" name="United Arab Emirates" shortname="United Arab Emirates">
<city id="192851" code="AUH" name="Abu Dhabi" shortname="Abu Dhabi">
<airport id="192853" code="AUH" name="Abu Dhabi" shortname="Abu Dhabi"></airport>
</city>
<city id="192855" code="DXB" name="Dubai" shortname="Dubai">
<airport id="192857" code="DXB" name="Dubai International Airport" shortname="Dubai"></airport>
</city>
</country>
</region>
</list>
```

1) Veiwalldestinations.xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:tlink="urn:TridionLinking" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:utils="urn:XSLTExtensions" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xlink tlink msxsl utils">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        Title:              View All the Destinations XHTML
        Description:  Render view all the destinations control
        Author:           Manoj Singh
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
  <xsl:include href="dynamic_linking.xslt"/>

  <!-- Translations are still loaded here because of XHTML content, research a way around that -->
  <xsl:key name="kCityById" match="city" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vLocations" select="document(concat($publicationPath, /list/resources/@location))/list"/>
  <xsl:variable name="destination" select="/list"/>
  <xsl:param name="publicationPath"/>
  <xsl:param name="pubURL"/>
  <xsl:param name="pageURL"/>

  <xsl:param name="region"/>
  <xsl:param name="country"/>

  <!-- root match -->
  <xsl:template match="/list">
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="$publicationPath"/>-->
    <div class="brownBarContainer">
      <div class="brownBar">
        All Destinations
      </div>
    </div>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="displayTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="first sortSelected">
            <div class="thPadding">
              <a class="iconDownSortArrow" href="#">Destination</a>           
            </div>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" class="sortHover">
            <div class="thPadding">
              <a class="iconSortArrowOff" href="#">Country</a>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" class="sortHover">
            <div class="thPadding">
              <a class="iconSortArrowOff" href="#">Region</a>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="destination"></xsl:apply-templates>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="destination">    
    <xsl:variable name="vReverseURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@url"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vCountryURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($vReverseURL,'/')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>/index.aspx</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vRegionURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(substring-after($vReverseURL,'/'),'/')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>/index.aspx</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$vLocations">         
      <tr>
        <td class="detail first">
          <a class="arrowSmallFront" href="{$current/@url}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$current/@title"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td class="detail noLeftBorder">
          <a class="arrowSmallFront" href="{$vCountryURL}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kCityById',$current/city/@id)/../@name"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td class="detail noLeftBorder">
          <a class="arrowSmallFront" href="{$vRegionURL}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kCityById',$current/city/@id)/../../@name"/>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>      
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template name="reverse">
    <xsl:param name="string" select="''"/>
    <xsl:if test="$string != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string,2)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($string,1,1)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you see there are two parameters in xslt, these are the **IDs** coming from the top usercontrol (selection)

```
 <xsl:param name="region"/>
  <xsl:param name="country"/>
```

Now I want to show the records according to region and country IDs passed, I am able to get all the records when there is no region and country IDs are passed. For example if region "asia & pacific' having **ID = 192393** is selected in usercontrol then only all the destinations related to that region will come and if user selects desired country in region, then it will only show the records related to that country only. for example if user selects region "asia & pacific" and country as "australia" then xslt will only show the "Sydney" and "Brisbane" according to above xmls.

The relation between **destinations.xml** and **locations.xmls** is with **city IDs**

Secondary, I want to sort the destination when user clicks on destination heading, please have a look to above xslt with below htmls

```
 <th scope="col" class="first sortSelected">
                <div class="thPadding">
                  <a class="iconDownSortArrow" href="#">Destination</a>           
                </div>
              </th>
```

Thanks and sorry for long questions. Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do filters with region and country with below xslt changes. It is also having pagination implemented.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:tlink="urn:TridionLinking" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:utils="urn:XSLTExtensions" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xlink tlink msxsl utils">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        Title:              View All the Destinations XHTML
        Description:  Render view all the destinations control
        Author:           Manoj Singh
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
  <xsl:include href="dynamic_linking.xslt"/>

  <!-- Translations are still loaded here because of XHTML content, research a way around that -->
  <xsl:key name="kCityById" match="city" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vLocations" select="document(concat($publicationPath, /list/resources/@location))/list"/>
  <xsl:variable name="destination" select="/list"/>
  <xsl:param name="publicationPath"/>
  <xsl:param name="pubURL"/>
  <xsl:param name="pageURL"/>

  <xsl:param name="region"/>
  <xsl:param name="country"/>


  <!-- offset controls the starting position of the results to show -->
  <xsl:param name="offset">0</xsl:param>
  <!-- blockSize controls how many results to show on a single page -->
  <xsl:param name="blockSize" select="15" />

  <!-- Amount of page links to show by default -->
  <xsl:param name="pagesShown">20</xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="totalHits" select="count(/list/destination[contains(concat($pubURL,@url),substring-before($pageURL,'/index.aspx'))])" />

  <xsl:template name="calcStart">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$offset = 0">1</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="($offset * $blockSize) + 1"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="calcEnd">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(($offset + 1) * $blockSize) > $totalHits">
        <xsl:value-of select="$totalHits"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="($offset + 1) * $blockSize"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="pageNavigation">
    <xsl:param name="pageCount"/>
    <xsl:param name="currPage"/>
    <xsl:param name="showPages">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$pagesShown > $pageCount">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pageCount"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="($pagesShown mod 2) = 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pagesShown"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pagesShown + 1"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="currEntry" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="offset">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($currPage &lt; $showPages) or ($pageCount = 1)">0</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$currPage > ($pageCount - $showPages + 1)">
          <xsl:value-of select="$pageCount - $showPages"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$currPage - ($showPages div 2) - 1"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:param>

    <!-- Header Processing -->
    <xsl:if test="$currEntry = 1">
      <xsl:if test="($pageCount > $showPages) and ($currPage >= $showPages)">
        <li>... </li>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="not ($currEntry > $showPages)">
      <li>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="($currEntry + $offset) = $currPage">
            <strong class="thisPage">
              <xsl:value-of select="$currEntry + $offset"/>
            </strong>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <a href="{utils:GetHashedUrl(concat($pageURL,'?offset=',$currEntry + $offset - 1,'&amp;blockSize=',$blockSize,'&amp;pagesShown=',$pagesShown))}">
              <xsl:value-of select="$currEntry + $offset"/>
            </a>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </li>

      <xsl:if test="not ($currEntry >=  $showPages)">
        <li class="separatorLine">|</li>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:call-template name="pageNavigation">
        <xsl:with-param name="pageCount" select="$pageCount"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="currPage" select="$currPage"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="showPages" select="$showPages"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="currEntry" select="$currEntry + 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="$offset"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

    <!-- Footer Processing -->
    <xsl:if test="$currEntry = 1">
      <xsl:if test="($pageCount > $showPages) and (($pageCount - $currPage + 1) >= $showPages)">
        <li> ...</li>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="displayPageNavigation">
    <div class="continueBar">
      <div class="continueBarLeft">
        <xsl:variable name="displayStart">
          <xsl:call-template name="calcStart"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="displayEnd">
          <xsl:call-template name="calcEnd"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <strong>
          <xsl:value-of select="utils:TextFormatted('DisplayingDestinations2Arg', concat($displayStart, '-', $displayEnd), $totalHits)"/>
        </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="continueBarRight">
        <ul class="paginationLinks">
          <!-- Show a back button when available -->
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$offset > 0">
              <li class="noBorder first">
                <a class="iconButtonBackBar" href="{$pageURL}?offset={$offset - 1}&amp;blockSize={$blockSize}&amp;pagesShown={$pagesShown}">
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                </a>
              </li>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <li class="noBorder first">
                <span class="iconButtonBackBarOff">
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                </span>
              </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

          <!-- Output the page navigation links -->
          <xsl:call-template name="pageNavigation">
            <xsl:with-param name="pageCount">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$blockSize >= $totalHits">1</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="($totalHits mod $blockSize) != 0">
                  <xsl:value-of select="ceiling($totalHits div $blockSize)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$totalHits div $blockSize"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="currPage" select="$offset + 1"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <!-- Show a next button when available -->
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(($offset + 1) * $blockSize) > $totalHits">
              <li class="last">
                <span class="iconButtonForwardBarOff">
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                </span>
              </li>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <li class="last">
                <a class="iconButtonForwardBar" href="{$pageURL}?offset={$offset + 1}&amp;blockSize={$blockSize}&amp;pagesShown={$pagesShown}">
                  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
                </a>
              </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="clearBoth">
        <xsl:comment/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- root match -->
  <xsl:template match="/list">
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="$publicationPath"/>-->
    <div class="brownBarContainer">
      <div class="brownBar">
        All Destinations
      </div>
    </div>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="displayTable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="first sortSelected">
            <div class="thPadding">
              <a class="iconDownSortArrow" href="#">Destination</a>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" class="sortHover">
            <div class="thPadding">
              <a class="iconSortArrowOff" href="#">Country</a>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th scope="col" class="sortHover">
            <div class="thPadding">
              <a class="iconSortArrowOff" href="#">Region</a>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$region='' and $country=''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="destination"></xsl:apply-templates>          
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$country!=''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="destination[city/@id=$vLocations/region/country[@id=$country]/city/@id]"></xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$region!=''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="destination[city/@id=$vLocations/region[@id=$region]/country/city/@id]"></xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="horRuleWhite">
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <xsl:call-template name="displayPageNavigation" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="destination">
    <xsl:variable name="vReverseURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="@url"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vCountryURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($vReverseURL,'/')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>/index.aspx</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vRegionURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(substring-after($vReverseURL,'/'),'/')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>/index.aspx</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$vLocations">
      <tr>
        <td class="detail first">
          <a class="arrowSmallFront" href="{$current/@url}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$current/@title"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td class="detail noLeftBorder">
          <a class="arrowSmallFront" href="{$vCountryURL}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kCityById',$current/city/@id)/../@name"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td class="detail noLeftBorder">
          <a class="arrowSmallFront" href="{$vRegionURL}">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kCityById',$current/city/@id)/../../@name"/>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="reverse">
    <xsl:param name="string" select="''"/>
    <xsl:if test="$string != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string,2)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($string,1,1)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I am still struggling, how to **sort** the data on the click of my link, please see the below HTML where I need sorting on click.

```
            <tr>
  <th scope="col" class="first sortSelected">
    <div class="thPadding">
      <a class="iconDownSortArrow" href="#">Destination</a>
    </div>
  </th>
  <th scope="col" class="sortHover">
    <div class="thPadding">
      <a class="iconSortArrowOff" href="#">Country</a>
    </div>
  </th>
  <th scope="col" class="sortHover">
    <div class="thPadding">
      <a class="iconSortArrowOff" href="#">Region</a>
    </div>
  </th>
    </tr>
```

I want to have sorting on the click of "Destination" , Country and Region. Please also have a look to code and suggest where do I need to modification.

Your Input is important to me!

Thanks.